# Why was Flash affected by the prison pudding in Season 4?

Tags: plot-explanation, arrowverse, the-flash

In Season 4 of *The Flash* when Barry Allen was in prison, when the warden figured out he was the Flash and gave him pudding tainted with tranquilizers, why did the tranquilizer in the pudding affect Barry?  Wouldn't his metabolism allow him to burn thru the tranquilizers, or couldn't his body vibrate through the tranquilizers like it did when Green Arrow shot him with horse tranquilizers in Season 1?

Answer (score 2):

To me it seemed that the prison boss had some knowledge about speedsters and has been well prepared. At least he was able to build a cell which Flash couldnt't vibe through.
Maybe he got help of Amunet Black, who knows pretty well about metas and their powers.

On the other side, I think Green Arrow was missing this kind of knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

There is a scene where the Flash is shown to be drinking too much alcohol but still not getting high. At that time, Cisco prepares a concentrated drink that makes him feel drunk. This pudding can be the same as that. He must have mixed a lot amount of tranquilizer in the pudding so that it takes time even for the faster metabolism of the Flash to burn through it.